# AngularFire 2 Query and Increment Value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

```
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.items = db.list('/articles');
}

addItem(createdOn: number, details: any, shorthand: string, title: string, id: number) {
  this.items.push({
    createdOn: 12345,
    details: "<p>Details go here...",
    shorthand: "shorthand-title-here",
    title: "Article Title",
    id: 1
  });
}
```

I'm going to replace the values with variables of course, except for the :id parameter.  Instead of just pushing a value to the JSON object like above, I need to first query all records in this.items, take the highest record of :id and increment it by 1.

So for example, if my query finds a record with an `:id` value of 7, I need to set the id variable to 8 and push that variable to `:id` when the addItem function is called.

Comment: I would advise against doing this in Firebase. Is there a reason why you really really really need the incrementing id?

Comment: Is there a way to replace the id that is inserted into the object with the key that is generated from the .push?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43969496/6156726