# Auto increment data on firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to create something like this on Firebase:

```
"Assets": {
    "asset001" : {
        "name": "DESK001",
        "owner: "owner's name",
        "brand: "HP",
    },
   "asset002" : {
        "name": "NOTE001",
        "owner: "owner's name",
        "brand: "Dell",
    },

   ...
}
```

But, i dont know how to automatically increment the value on "asset001"... i have seen the push() method, but then i wouldn't know how to retrieve the data. Here's what i have so far:

JavaScript

```
//Get the inputs ID from HTML
var inputName = document.getElementById("inputName");
var inputOwner = document.getElementById("inputOwner");
var inputBrand = document.getElementById("inputBrand");
var inputAsset = document.getElementById("inputAsset");

//Set values on FireBase    
btnAsset.addEventListener('click', e => {
//Get inputs data
const asset = inputAsset.value;
const owner = inputOwner.value;
const brand = inputBrand.value;
const name = inputName.value;

//database reference
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Assets");

//setar os valores
rootRef.child(asset).child("owner").set(owner);
rootRef.child(asset).child("brand").set(brand);
rootRef.child(asset).child("name").set(name);
```

Comment: The Firebase documentation explicitly recommends using `push()` for ordered collections: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data. There's also extensive experience that speaks against using sequential, consecutive numeric indexes, such as you're trying here. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be going through a lot of trouble trying to make names for your assets. The way you are creating your keys you will run into trouble once you reach Asset999.

The best way to ensure that you do not have to bother with creating a unique key is letting firebase do it for you. Then upload all the info in one go.

```
var newKey = rootRef.push().key;

var objectToUpload = {
"owner": owner,
"brand": brand,
"name": name
};

rootRef.child(newKey).set(objectToUpload);
```

Comment: Well, it should work this way, but then i would have to make some sort of rule or condition to guarantee that the "name" field is not repeated, each asset needs to have some sort of name that the user needs to know...

Comment: How do i get the reference of this newKey on another page? Consider that i'm setting the data on page1.html/page1.js and i want to list this data on a table on another page (index.html/index.js), I can get the "owner", "brand", "name" values, but i cant get the object ID in there.. i'm using something like this:

var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Assets");

rootRef.on("child_changed", snap => {

var owner= snap.child("owner").val();
var brand= snap.child("brand").val();
var name= snap.child("name").val();

Comment: Again, it makes more sense to use objects rather than individual variables.

Comment: You can get the ID by var assetID = snap.key, then the content by var newAsset = snap.val(), then you can access the values by newAsset.brand, newAsset.name, and newAsset.owner.